# Set-Cookies response header cookies not correctly and immediately set on VPS

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, apache2, vuex, vps

I have a Spring Boot app and some static files made with Vue on my Virtual Private Server using Apache Web Server.

I have a problem that the cookies from the backend are not set, more specifically, they don't show up in the developers tools.

Locally everything works fine, and it works in the following way:

1. land on landing page /login
2. fill in credentials and call /api/login (backend)
3. in response headers I see 'Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=ed5479d8-75e0-4a48-affd-e02ded1c17e0; Path=/' and multiple other response headers
4. cookies show up in developer tools
5. access arbitrary other endpoint (e.g. /create-pools)
6. see that XSRF-TOKEN cookie is sent back to the backend
7. see that the X-XSRF-TOKEN cookie as header is also sent to the backend resulting in a successful call

On my VPS the flow should be the same, but instead:

1. land on landing page /login
2. fill in credentials and call /api/login (backend)
3. in response headers I see 'Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=ed5479d8-75e0-4a48-affd-e02ded1c17e0; Path=/' and multiple other response headers
4. cookies DO NOT show up in developer tools
5. access arbitrary other endpoint (e.g. /create-pools)
6. see that XSRF-TOKEN cookie is sent back to the backend
7. X-XSRF-TOKEN cookie is not sent back to the backend resulting in an unsuccessful call

So somehow on my VPS it doesn't use or set the cookies.

Worth mentioning is that in the apache configuration I have:

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/SSL_certificate_www_test_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.test.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.test.com.cer

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/bart/test/static/
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com

    <Directory /home/bart/test/static>
            AllowOverride All

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . index.html [L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-test-com.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8082
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8082
```

What I have tried so far, but didn't work:

- look into `withCredentials` properties on XHR call (I have it added, but setting it true by default doesn't change anything)
- Manually read XSRF-TOKEN cookie to see if its present. It printed `undefined`, but it strangely is sent to the backend as:
  Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=ed5479d8-75e0-4a48-affd-e02ded1c17e0; in the request headers (so somehow there should be a cookie)
- set domain name of cookie in Spring to test.com (so that it doesn't set cookies to localhost)
- set path name of cookie in Spring to /

In proxypass I send /api calls to the backend. The strange thing is that once I manually navigate to test.com/api suddenly the cookies showup (with path /). If I, after that, navigate to another page then suddenly the cookies are there. It seems like I first manually have to access a /api endpoint (which is not a page but an HTTP to the backend) before the cookies show up.

How do I solve this for me unknown problem?

Regards,

Bart

Comment: Are the problem requests CORS requests? For cross-origin cookies it is normal that you can't access them via `document.cookie`. It can also be difficult to see them in the developer tools: you may need to open another browser tab to a URL from the appropriate origin so that you can see them (it doesn't matter what URL you access so long as it is for the correct server).

Comment: @skirtle The problem doesnt seem to be related to CORS. I do set CORS headers, methods and origins in the backend, but those are working as expected.

Comment: If you are using CORS then that is highly significant and very likely the source of your problems. However, just because you are setting those headers does not necessarily mean you are using CORS, they can also be set on a non-CORS request. So please can you clarify whether you are actually using CORS for the problem requests?

Comment: @skirtle so the problem might be solved by completely removing the cors configuration and thus accepting all requests? 

To answer your question: I only set Cors headers, methods and origins in the backend, so if a request doesnt comply to those configurations it will fail. Im not sending any cors specific headers in the request. So im guessing im not using CORS?

Comment: @skirtle coming back to my previous comment, I dont think these are CORS requests since my frontend runs on the server as well as my backend and thus have the same origin.

Comment: If all requests are using the same origin then CORS won't be in play. It does fit several of the symptoms rather well but if you aren't using it then it can't be that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it seems to be resolved by changing the way I call the backend. Previously, I called it using https://test.com/api, but I saw that request that used https://www.test.com/api got the cookies set correctly. Whereas the https://test.com/api calls did not. Therefore, I changed the way I call the backend by adding www.

I have no idea why it works this way, but it seems to have solved the problem. If anyone has any idea as to why, please feel free to add a comment. For now I will approve this as the answer.

Thanks all for considering my question.

Bart